# SAP oData: How do I execute a DEEP INSERT through postman and SCP oData provisioning?

Tags: postman, odata, sap-cloud-platform

I have a DEEP INSERT set up in ABAP + SAP Gateway Client.

The issue is I can only run this through SAP GATEWAY CLIENT, not through Postman (externally).

E.g. I've setup my service in SCP oData provisioning...

First Call gets my auth-token for the client.

https://oauthasservices-xxxxxx.hana.ondemand.com/oauth2/api/v1/token?grant_type=client_credentials

Second Call performs a GET to FETCH the X-CSRF-TOKEN (This is done automatically through SAP Gateway Client)

https://gwaas-xxxxxx.hana.ondemand.com/odata/SAP/ZGW_XXX_SRV/orderSet?FromOrder

Lastly I run a POST Call using the Authentication `+ X-CSRF-TOKEN`, and exactly the same payload as my call in SAP Gateway Client.

https://gwaas-adddcbbb0.hana.ondemand.com/odata/SAP/ZGW_JUSTEAT_SRV/orderSet?FromOrder

This returns

> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERRORCould not perform the operation, contact your System Administrator: Transaction ID :4d237684-b708-4b8a-9b88-xxxxxxxxxx

I have a breakpoint in my **DEEP_INSERT** method which is triggered when ran through the SAP Gateway Client, but not through postman.

Any ideas?